# Laravel Eloquent get specific relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to get the books where the authors are from a specific country, for now my query looks like this :

```
$books->with('author')->where('country', '=',  'FR');
```

but the where is applied to books and not to authors

any help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **whereHas()** for that. The following code should do the trick:

```
$country = 'FR';
$books = Book::with('author')->whereHas('author', function($query) use ($country) {
  $query->where('country', '=',  $country);
})->get();
```

This will give you all books that have a related author, that has **country** column set to **FR**.

Comment: Thank you ! Can i pass another argument to the closure ? i tried but i got an error Missing argument 2

Comment: What do you want to pass? You can't do that really, but I guess what you mean is using from variables outer scope inside the closure. I've updated the answer